# How to handle invalid_identifier exception in pl/sql?

Tags: oracle, exception, plsql, dynamic-sql

i need to check if a certain SELECT statement includes a field (column) that doesn't exists in a table, for example:

select col1, col2, col3 from table1

if col1 dosen't exists i want to show "missing field", instead for the user to get an invalid identifier error.

what is my best and short option to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This code fragment should get you started:

```
set serveroutput on
DECLARE
   exc_invalid_id EXCEPTION;
   PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(exc_invalid_id, -904);
   l_message   VARCHAR2(4000);
BEGIN
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE '
      SELECT col1
           , col2
           , col3
        FROM table1
   ';
EXCEPTION
   WHEN exc_invalid_id THEN
      l_message := regexp_replace(sqlerrm, '^[A-Z]{3}-[0-9]{5}: "([^"]+)".*$', '\1');

      dbms_output.put_line ( 'missing field '''||l_message||'''');
      dbms_output.put_line ( 'exception: sqlcode='||SQLCODE||', sqlerrm='''||sqlerrm||'''');

   WHEN OTHERS THEN
      RAISE;
END;
/
show errors
```

Explanation:

- You declare a user-defined exception.
- You associate the exception with the Oracle error thrown on an unknown column identifier, whose code is `00904`.
- The sql query is executed as native dynamic sql - otherwise the code wouldn't compile in the first place.
- The error message is composed from the text of your choice complemented by the offending column name. This name is extracted from the oracle error message by means of a regular expression. Note that this example hasn't been tested for the case of multiple offending names - however, you should get the drift.
- The second line of output produces the original error message and is contained for illustrative purposes only.
- The exception handler responds to your exception only and re-raises any other exception to be handled in one of the surrounding blocks.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
 select 1
 from   user_tab_columns
 where  table_name = '<your table name>'  and
        column_name = '<your column name>'
```

That will only work for tables in the same schema. Replace with ALL_TAB_COLUMNS view if you need other schemas.  If no row is returned, then no column exists. I am assuming this is for dynamic SQL, since for static SQL you will get a compile error if the column is missing anyways.